# dynamic tables with pagination in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing web scraping with selenium and I find the problem of iterating over a table, this is the html code
It has pages with numbers like -> 1,2,3,4,5,...20 the first 5 numbers to turn the page of the table I can click on them, but when it reaches... it tells me that it can't find the object.

The problem is when I substitute the `<li class="paginate_button page-item disabled" id="vehicle-compatibility-table_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="vehicle-compatibility-table" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">…</a></li>` for the 6, since it is not in the hmtl code, it fails, but I cannot get the table dynamic

Html code

```html
<li class="paginate_button page-item disabled" id="vehicle-compatibility-table_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="vehicle-compatibility-table" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">…</a></li>
```

Python code:

```py
listado_hojas = list(range(2, 100))
for i in listado_hojas: 
     try: 
         time.sleep(2)         
         element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/main/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[{}]'.format(i))
                element.click()       
      except Exception as e:
          # Print the exception message
            print(f"An exception occurred: {str(e)}")
```

I am trying to get the data from a table with Selenium.

Comment: [this is similar to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984221/unable-to-click-next-button-using-selenium-as-number-of-pages-are-unknown). do add url of the page in your question.

Comment: Can you please share the URL?

Comment: Is it a public URL so we can access?